# Schedule localnotificacion on specific days ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, localnotification

I have an Ionic 2 app that schedules notifications with: [LocalNotificacions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/)

I create notifications like:

```
let options = {
    id: reminder.id,
    text: this.NOTIFICATION_TEXT,
    at: reminder.date,
    sound: this.notifySoundPath,
    every: "day",
    data: notificationData
};
```

And it schedules notifications that repeat every day at this time.

Now, I need to create notifications that repeat in specific days. The user should can select dates such monday, tuesday, wednesday,etc. And I need to be able to schedule reminders that will repeat on these days.

Can I do it with this plugin?

Thank's in advance.